# Parallel loops in Thymeleaf

Tags: thymeleaf

This is my code, it does not work. I know I can not put the loops that, but how should they be to get the logic done

```
<tr th:each="max:${top3max}", th:each="min:${top3min}">
          <td th:text="${max.getName()}"></td>
          <td th:text="${min.getName()}"></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: `it does not work` doesn't explain **how it should work**.

Comment: Did you try with `<th:block">`?

Answer (score 0):

As long as both `Lists` are the same size, you can loop through one and use the status variable to access the other.  Like this:

```
<tr th:each="max, i: ${top3max}">
  <td th:text="${max.getName()}"></td>
  <td th:text="${top3min[i.index]}"></td>
</tr>
```

If you want something more like a traditional for loop, this will work (as long as top3max is a List -- you'll have to use `.length` instead of `.size()` if you're dealing with an array.

```
<tr th:each="i: ${#numbers.sequence(0, top3max.size() - 1)}">
  <td th:text="${top3max[i]}"></td>
  <td th:text="${top3min[i]}"></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: With no details about your requirements, I can only make guesses.  You can use `th:if` to show or hide the rows, or make sure your lists are never empty in the controller.

Comment: My idea is that a user can have top-3 results, but he may not.
If the user has the results, it works well, but if it does not break.
In one table I have to put 2 columns, one for the max results and the other for the min. 
--Thank you very much for the answer to my problem--

Comment: Like I said, that's an easy check with `th:if`:  `<table th:if="${...}">` where you fill in the expression to determine if the user has results or not.